# Running Count Total with PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm fairly close to this solution, but I just need a little help getting over the end.

I'm trying to get a running count of the occurrences of client_ids regardless of the date, however I need the dates and ids to still appear in my results to verify everything.

I found part of the solution [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/47-How-to-calculate-Running-Totals-and-Sums-in-SQL.html) but have not been able to modify it enough for my needs.

Here is what the answer should be, counting if the occurrences of the client_ids sequentially :

```
id  client_id   deliver_on  running_total
1   138         2017-10-01  1
2   29          2017-10-01  1
3   138         2017-10-01  2
4   29          2013-10-02  2
5   29          2013-10-02  3
6   29          2013-10-03  4
7   138         2013-10-03  3
```

However, here is what I'm getting:

```
id  client_id   deliver_on  running_total
1   138         2017-10-01  1
2   29          2017-10-01  1
3   138         2017-10-01  1
4   29          2013-10-02  3
5   29          2013-10-02  3
6   29          2013-10-03  1
7   138         2013-10-03  2
```

Rather than counting the times the client_id appears sequentially, the code counts the time the id appears in the previous date range.

Here is my code and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

```
SELECT n.id, n.client_id, n.deliver_on, COUNT(n.client_id) AS "running_total"

FROM orders n 

LEFT JOIN orders o 
    ON (o.client_id = n.client_id 
            AND n.deliver_on > o.deliver_on)          

GROUP BY n.id, n.deliver_on, n.client_id
ORDER BY n.deliver_on ASC
```

*** EDIT WITH ANSWER ***

I ending up solving my own question. Here is the solution with comments:

```
-- Set "1" for counting to be used later

WITH DATA AS (

SELECT

   orders.id, 
   orders.client_id, 
   orders.deliver_on,
   COUNT(1) -- Creates a column of "1" for counting the occurrences

   FROM orders

   GROUP BY 1

   ORDER BY deliver_on, client_id

)

SELECT

   id,
   client_id,
   deliver_on,
   SUM(COUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id 
                           ORDER BY client_id, deliver_on 
                           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) -- Counts the sequential client_ids based on the number of times they appear

 FROM DATA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the answer posted to close the question:

```
-- Set "1" for counting to be used later
WITH DATA AS (

SELECT

   orders.id, 
   orders.client_id, 
   orders.deliver_on,
   COUNT(1) -- Creates a column of "1" for counting the occurrences

   FROM orders

   GROUP BY 1

   ORDER BY deliver_on, client_id

)

SELECT

   id,
   client_id,
   deliver_on,
   SUM(COUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id 
                           ORDER BY client_id, deliver_on 
                           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) -- Counts the sequential client_ids based on the number of times they appear

 FROM DATA
```